# npm install error: what does this mean exactly? How to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, npm, dependencies

While using npm install I had the following error: what should I do about it and should I worry? How do I contact the author?

```
17723 error code E404
17724 error 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@babel/plugin-transform-named-capturing-types-regex/-/plugin-transform-named-capturing-types-regex-7.4.2.tgz
17725 error 404
17726 error 404 '@babel/plugin-transform-named-capturing-types-regex@7.4.2' is not in the npm registry.
17727 error 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
17728 error 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'front_end'
17729 error 404 Note that you can also install from a
17730 error 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
17731 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

404 means not found. I.e. no package was published under that name.

Did you mean this one ?:

```
npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-named-capturing-groups-regex
```

Comment: I just used "npm install" to install all dependencies of my project, but I never had that error before.

Comment: perhaps it was renamed - does it work with the above package?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think it's something connected to react-create-app that was autoinstalled.

Comment: ok but does it work when you install this one? If so, pls mark as correct..

Comment: I didn't use your command, but the issue is gone after doing npm audit fix, npm update and finally npm install again.

Comment: ok so check package.json - I bet '@babel/plugin-transform-named-capturing-groups-regex' is now installed...